# callback function for string in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone know how to design the callback function for string in Codeigniter?if use this function for int,it works.for string,the validation does not work.here is my model:

```
> function check_user_name($User_Name='')
>     {
>         $this -> db -> select('User_Name');
>         $this -> db -> from('login');
>         $this -> db -> where('User_Name',$User_Name);
>         $this -> db -> limit(1);
>         $query = $this -> db -> get();
>             
>         if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
>         {
>             return $query->result();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
```

and here is my controller:

form validation

> `$this->form_validation->set_rules('User_Name','User_Name','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_User_Name');`

```
> function check_User_Name($User_Name)
>     {
>         //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
> 
>         $row = $this->UserRegistration->check_user_name($User_Name);//query the
> database
> 
>         if($row)
>         {
>             return TRUE;
>         }
>         else 
>         {
>             $this->form_validation->set_message('check_User_Name', 'The User_Name already exist.Please use other User_Name.Thank you.');
>             return FALSE;
>         }
>     }
```

Answer (score 0):

put your validation script in function.

function check_User_Name($User_Name)
         {
             //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    if($this->form_validation-set_rules('User_Name','User_Name','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_User_Name'))
    {

```
         $row = $this->UserRegistration->check_user_name($User_Name);//query the
 database

         if($row)
        {
             return TRUE;
         }
        else 
         {
             $this->form_validation->set_message('check_User_Name', 'The User_Name already exist.Please use other User_Name.Thank you.');
            return FALSE;
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: thanks for reply.yr suggestion can print out the message but the if else statement not function.both printing out the same message.is there any mistake at my model?